# Git set-url origin

Tags: git

Server:

```
repo1.git (old code)
repo2.git (latest code)
```

Workstation:

```
repo1> git remote set-url origin ssh://repo2.git
repo1> git remote -v (yes, I see that the origin has changed)
repo1> git pull
```

Appears to pull down the latest code from repo2 as it has the latest tags and I can see several files with code changes.  However, if I try to revert back:

```
repo1> git remote set-url origin ssh://repo1.git
repo1> git remote -v (yes, I see that the origin has changed back to repo1)
repo1> git pull
```

It now says that the repo is up-to-date where I was expecting it to pull the old code back down.  What am I missing?

Thanks! (new Git user)

Comment: Are you doing all of these commands from the same folder?

Comment: Yes, inside repo1.  The first part seems to work as I would expect - wanting to update the code base for repo1 to the latest code, which resides in repo2.  The reverting back however it not working as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If your branch is ahead of the remote branch, Git will never discard your local commits (that would be really bad if you had just authored a bunch of commits).

If you want to revert your branch to an older commit pointed to by a branch on a different remote, you need to `git fetch` and then `git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>`. You're effectively instructing Git to discard a bunch of work from the branch to go back to an earlier point in time, which is not a usual workflow with Git.

Odds are you achieve your goals by just adding a *second* remote and leaving it in place, rather than switching around the URL of the first remote.

Comment: These repos come from an external vendor, the latest repo being the latest code.  How then would I update my local repo and/or revert back if I needed to - what would be the proper workflow?  (I do not edit or commit any changes to this code, but do need the latest copy on my workstation for compilation).

Comment: You can leave your local branch alone, and instead check out a new branch pointed at the other repo's state. Assuming we're talking about the branch `master`, You would add the remote, `git remote add repo2 ssh://repo2.git`, fetch, `git fetch`, and then make a new branch pointing at `repo2/master`: `git checkout -b repo2-master repo2/master`

Comment: Also, if you're not committing anything, then you don't need *branches* at all. Just add the second remote as above, but check out the commits directly: `git checkout repo1/master` or `git checkout repo2/master`. This will leave you in a "detached head" state, which doesn't matter if you don't intend to commit anything. Remember to `git fetch` periodically to pull down the latest changes from your remotes.

Comment: How would I set the HEAD to repo2/master?

Comment: @user2296256 `git checkout repo2/master`